# Get a list of emails

Tags: evernote

I am new to evernote. I want to work with evernote javascript SDK, as js is what I understand best. So my task is to get a list of e-mails from evernote.(get an array of emails). I have some web pages that are saved in evernote.

How can I retrieve an email from each web page?

I know how to do this from a webpage in browser. But evernote seems to have some crossorigin restrictions. So it is only possible with node.js as i understand.

What I have done already: registered new test api key, downloaded and installed SDK by NPM, what next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evernote JS API doesn't support CORS as stated here: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js#does-the-api-support-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing

So you need a server-side code (e.g. on Node.js, see the provided example: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js/tree/master/sample/express) that does the communication with Evernote servers, and then can pass this information down to the browser.